# change symbol size and drop summary from ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a newcomer to plotting graphics in R and could use help figuring out a ggplot legend issue.  I've written this code, with my abbreviated dataset included first:

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L), .Label = c("11/11/2016", "12/2/2016"), class = "factor"), 
                   site = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
                   ), .Label = c("mk", "tf"), class = "factor"), factor = c(2L, 
                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                                            10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                                            541L), individual = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                                                                                  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                  4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                  8L, 9L, 10L), temp = c(-19.85, -19.94, -20.77, -21.3, -21.71, 
                                                                                                                         -21.88, -22.03, -22.74, -22.86, -16.63, -19.01, -19.67, -20.47, 
                                                                                                                         -21.14, -21.23, -23.01, -24.43, -24.61, -24.76, -19.09, -18.88, 
                                                                                                                         -19.02, -19.22, -19.32, -19.32, -19.55, -19.68, -20.23, -20.32, 
                                                                                                                         -21.37, -15.9, -18.87, -19.02, -19.16, -19.44, -19.62, -22.38, 
                                                                                                                         -24.37, -24.92, -26.9)), .Names = c("date", "site", "factor", 
                                                                                                                                                             "individual", "temp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -40L))

library(ggplot2)
library(plotrix) #loads standard error function

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(date), fill = factor(site), y = temp)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', method = 'histodot', binwidth = 0.3, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  labs(title="data plot",x = "sampling date", y = "response temp (°C)") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name  ="",
                      breaks=c("mk", "tf"),
                      labels=c("site 1", "site 2")) +
  theme(legend.position="top") 
  #guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=xx))) # this last line doesn't seem to change the size of the legend dots.. 

p 

#mean dot with standard error lines:
m.sterr <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x)
  ymin <- m-std.error(x)
  ymax <- m+std.error(x)
  return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
}

p + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=m.sterr, color="black", position=position_dodge(0.5), size = .25)
```

This produced the following dot plot:

[dot plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wingg.png)

A challenge I encountered was my black stat_summary symbols obscure the fill aesthetic legend key.  When I change the stat_summary size argument to a very small value, it makes the colors in the underlying fill aesthetic key visible, but the summary objects in the plot itself become too small.  I think this could be resolved by either

(1) increasing the size of only the fill aesthetic legend symbols enough that that key can be easily discerned, or

(2) even cleaner, just making the black dots and bar summary symbols disappear from the legend.

I haven't figured out how to do either of these yet.  For (1), I tried adding `guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=xx)))` and tweaking the size argument, but this didn't have any effect.

Any suggestions to accomplish fixes (1) or (2) above, or an even better fix for my legend dilemma?

This is my first post, so I'm still learning what I need to include.  Let me know if more details are needed.  And thanks for any ideas.

Joshua

Comment: For 1) look [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guide_legend.html), `keywidth` and `keyheight` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: For (1), you were  close, but you need `fill = guide_legend...` rather than `colour`, because you used a `fill` aesthetic for the plot. For (2), add `show.legend=FALSE` to `stat_summary`.

Comment: For future reference, yes we do need your data. Otherwise, we need to take the time to find or create our own data set and adapt it to your code so that we can test out potential solutions. Make it easy for the people who are trying to help you by providing code and data that we can just copy and paste into our R sessions. To include a data sample, paste into your question the output of `dput(my_data_sample)`. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info on how to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you eipie10 and all who gave feedback on improving this question.  Even though you already led me to my answer, I thought it would be worthwhile editing the question to make it passable for SO.  Below is the output of sessionInfo().  Thanks again!

Comment: R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1